# Stream interrupted (client disconnected)

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, fine-tuning

when I use

```
 openai api fine_tunes.create -t data_prepared.jsonl -m davinci
```

I found error in my code

```
 Stream interrupted (client disconnected).
To resume the stream, run:

  openai api fine_tunes.follow -i <myfinetuning id>
```

but when I follow same this file this will be error same I will use

```
openai==0.25
```

but It cannot work for me

Can you help me solve this problem?